# Специализация шаблона контейнеров

Tags: шаблоны-с++, c++-cli

Извиняйте, но никак не могу найти даже направление для решения ситуации. Вопрос таков: Имеется класс-контейнер, который определен через шаблон

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>

public ref class FormContainer

{
private:
  T1^ container;
  List<T2^>^ elements;
  ...
  Int32 currentContainerItem();

public:
  property Int32 currentElementId
  {
    Int32 get
    {
      return currentContainerItem();
    }
  }
  ...
};
```

Для T1 будут использоваться различные виды контейнеров (ComboBox, ListBox, DataGridView). Мне необходимо получать текущий элемент текущего контейнера. Я не вижу никакой способ, кроме специализации метода для этого действия - **currentContainerItem**. Метод будет действовать для каждого из типов контейнеров.

Моя попытка реализации (для ComboBox) оказывается ошибочной, но я не могу понять почему...

```
template<typename T2>
inline Int32 FormContainer<ComboBox, T2>::currentContainerIndex()
{
    return container->SelestedIndex;
}
```

Я не хочу, чтобы местные гуру написали, как сделать правильное решение. Я прошу Вас направить мой мозг в правильное русло и подсказать причину ошибки.

Comment: Хотел бы спросить, вы C++/CLI используете по работе, или из "любви к искусству"?

Comment: никакой любви, только из-за предпочтений начальника

Comment: я сам поклонник нативных плюсов. бывший студент - нынче выпускник.